# Android application running in background application communicating with USB device

Tags: android, web-services, background-process

I have an application that communicates to an external camera over USB that needs to run for a long time collecting and processing images (astronomy stacking). Basically it may need to stay up for hours.

It communicates to the user via browser/HTTP - mostly because it is the only cross platform way I was able to implement it - so it runs on Android, Linux and headless PI.

The Android application itself is very simple. It has "start" button and gets USB access permission for actual C++ service that communicates to device and handles all HTTP Rest services and web-UI.

Now as obvious solution I run the thread that does all the job

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ols.run(); // run C++ code that does the job
        }
    }).start();
```

Now the app closes after 5-10 minutes without warning - even without USB device but with fake "image generator". From what I've read it is expected behavior and I need to have special handling background processing but I'm really confused as somebody new to Android world.

There are several options I see:

- Android [Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) but I find workflow confusing - especially since the program runs all the time.
- There is [Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent) that seems like fits the needs but I don't understand what is "foreground" processing.
- There is [Foreground Serices](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) probably also fit the bill

I'm really confused and I don't know which API and its variant is most suitable for my case.